# Widow, Widowed; Widower, What?

Tags: verbs, gender-positive

A woman who loses her husband is a widow; she is widowed. A man who loses his wife is a widower. Is there an equivalent male term for widowed?

Comment: Widowed: 
having become a widow or a widower. - .http://www.thefreedictionary.com/widowed

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20931/why-is-a-woman-a-widow-and-a-man-a-widower

Answer (score 3):

Widowed is to widower as widowed is to widow.

According to NOAD,

> **widow** *verb*, make into a widow or widower.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/widowered) suggested "widowered", oddly enough - although "widowed" would be perfectly acceptable in my experience.

> noun: a man who has lost his spouse by death and has not remarried.

and further:

> Related forms: widowered, adjective

Comment: That tells you exactly what you need to know about dictionary.com. ;-)

Comment: @MετάEd - Merriam-Webster any better? ;-) "made a widower *his widowered father — William Humphrey*" - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/widowered

Comment: For what it's worth, widowered does not appear in NOAD

Comment: It should be noted in the answer that for practical purposes nobody uses "widowered". its use is so rare that it might be considered an error along the lines of "misunderestimate". In 1900 its use was less than 0.1% of "widowed", which is where it is today. There was a tiny surge in the 20th century, peaking at 0.7% in 1963. In 19C publications, it is even more rare. Source: Google Ngram Viewer. The earliest citation in NED is 1852. "Widowerhood", "widowership", and "widowery", equally rare, have also been seen. Source: New English Dictionary V10B. They've just never caught on.