# Is it widow or widower in a same-sex marriage?

Tags: nouns, gender-positive

There are a lot of [widow questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324773/widow-widowed-widower-what) here on SE.

My same-sex partner has passed away, and today I referred to myself as a widower.  But it appears in the Collins English Dictionary that a widower is a man whose wife has died and who has not remarried.  It also has a very heavy connotation that I was married to a woman.

**Is it exclusively any man who loses a partner is a widower, and any woman (even should she be in a same-sex marriage) who loses a spouse is a widow?**  Is there another term more appropriate for me to use?

Comment: Historical use can guide us, but only collective, continuing use will define these terms going forward. I would expect anyone who identifies as a man and loses a spouse to be called a widower, and anyone who identifies as a woman and loses a spouse to be called a widow. Time will tell whether or not my prediction is accurate.

Comment: @Davo - thanks, I was unsure whether that assumption had been modified by new terminology or expectations of what each word meant.

Comment: Google claims over 9000 instances of ***gay widower***, and I expect most of them refer to "same-sex" bereaved. The gender implications of ***-er*** apply to the surviving partner - there's nothing other than "statistical average" telling you what sex the deceased was. Which puts widowed lesbians at a linguistic disadvantage, I guess, since ***gay widows*** might often refer to [***cougars***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cougar)

Comment: In my area, *widower* is actually rare to hear; both man and woman will rather refer to themselves as a *widow* if they have lost a spouse. Perhaps this could be seen as a sign of a trend towards gender neutral language. Otherwise, you could simply use the verb: I was widowed.

Comment: The dictionary just needs to be updated to use `partner` - I would not personally be bothered with the current definition which I would expect would only be an issue among people who anyway define _marriage_ as a pact made under god between one man and one woman... If you ignore the _wife_ part then you are a widower if you identify as male in my opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers why would _gay widow_ and _cougars_ have anything in common? Cougars are older women looking for young men - where is the gay and widow part?

Comment: I would assume that the dictionary just hasn't been updated since same-sex marriage has been legally recognised in a significant fraction of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @mplungian *gay* as a synonym for *merry*. *Widow* as an old woman. *Merry widow* in [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/merry_widow).

Comment: @ChrisH that's may well be a witticism, but hardly evidence that people confuse the expression for an older woman who has lost her younger husband. Why would she be necessarily *pleased*? Yes, I know Fumblefingers said it first...

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I can't find FF's comment any more, but was only attempting to clarify the phrase FF suggested. The classic *merry* (or *gay*) *widow* is enjoying looking for a (possibly younger hence FF's "cougar") new partner.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you are getting this completely wrong. "Gay" has two completely different meanings: A homosexual man, or a happy person. An older woman who is glad that she has her freedom back after the death of her husband, and who is now looking for a relationship with a younger man, could be called a "merry widow" or a "gay widow". A lesbian woman who is unconsolable about the death of her female partner could also be called a "gay widow". Unfortunate that the same words could be used for two totally different situations.

Comment: @gnasher729 no. I am not getting this completely wrong, I was saying why should an older woman = *cougar* be pleased/content = *gay* if her younger husband were to die. Who would think a "gay widow" refers to the aforementioned situation? Nowadays, *gay* refers, primarily, to someone homosexual. End of. Please see FF comment, third from top, `Which puts widowed lesbians at a linguistic disadvantage, I guess, since gay widows might often refer to cougars`  I took it to be a wry witticism, but if it was a serious consideration, I thoroughly disagree with it.

Comment: I have never heard of cougar to refer to anything other than a mature woman seeking a younger man (I've never heard any of my lesbian friends say that about a mature woman seeking a younger woman, but that could be bias).  I'm happy to be proven incorrect.  @Kasenjo - that is interesting, and probably where we will be headed where I am as well.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Perhaps it's an age thing. The *gay=homosexual* usage barely existed when I was growing up, so for me ***gay widow*** still naturally has associations with the more well-established ***merry widow***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Davo6 is right above that these terms are being expanded from their original context and time will tell how they end up being applied.

At the moment, **[widower](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228917)** is the term for a bereaved male spouse and **[widow](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228912)** his female equivalent. [The male term is much less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=widow%2Cwidower&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but male survivors of mixed-sex marriages are much less common. If you don't like the noun, there's always the plain adjective **bereaved**.

You're right about the connotations... but marriage itself has those connotations to some and, even where it doesn't any longer, it did until recently. You are part of the first generation to deal with this part of the human experience in the open. You can choose any term you like and the rest of us will just share our condolences on your loss.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could say "I am widowed" to show you have lost your spouse, but to avoid the gender complications of "a widow" and "a widower".

Answer (score 0):

I am widowed, male, and gay. This thread is interesting, a bit painful, and confounding. Of course, collective, continuing use will prevail, but as a relatively new social development - to have legally married people whose same-sex partners have died - what becomes common will depend in part on what we claim. I submit this post to add resonance for making the term 'widow' gender-neutral. I am not a widower because I didn't lose a wife; I lost a partner. Perhaps the term 'widower' will evaporate into insignificance as all of us who live on after our partners have died become 'widows.'

Answer (score -1):

W is used to refer to a woman, wife, widow, widower.
I suggest having a word that uses G.
Perhaps Gaysur, Gay survivor of a marriage. Thus, I am a Gaysur!

Comment: "Woman" comes from "wife-man" but "widow/widower" are more etymologically related to "wood" than they are "woman/wife" (not to mention the fact that a widower is traditionally a man). Without any evidence that it's used, I don't think that "gaysur" is a good alternative. (The meaning certainly isn't obvious.)

Comment: _Gay survivor of a marriage_ suggests that marriage was some form of conflict that you've managed to survive. That might be true for you but not for everyone.

Comment: @Laurel: It is worth noting that when the term meaning "wife-man" was applied in OE, it used *man* not in the male sense but in the human sense, and was used for men and women; *wer* was the term meaning a male person (cf. werewolf). The term *man* meaning what we use it to mean today (mostly) did not get fixed until the 13th century.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].