# Is "widower" the only word that adds a suffix for men?

Tags: suffixes, gender-positive

The word "widow" is for women, while the male version adds "-er" onto it.

I can't think of any other words in English that does this. There's words where male and female have different endings ("actor" versus "actress"), and cases where you specify maleness by putting "male" at the front ("male nurse", "male prostitute", "male geisha"), but nothing where you take an existing word, fail to remove anything, and then add some suffix. Are there any such words?

Comment: There is the bridegroom.

Comment: To be pedantic, and where else can you expect to be, the '-er' may very well  not be a suffix. It looks like it, but it could be the word forms came from differently inflected forms, viz. German cognates Witwer/Witwe (just different masculine and feminine endings)

Comment: @Helmar. One could contest that "groom" is a suffix. I would call "bridegroom" a compound.

Comment: Related: [Why is a woman a “widow” and a man a “widower”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20931)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [An Easy English Grammar for Beginners](https://books.google.com/books?id=AsADAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22The%20old%20word%20for%20duck%20was%20and%22%20andrake&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjww52p8ZHPAhXLcT4KHXZyCj0Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20old%20word%20for%20duck%20was%20and%22%20andrake&f=false) (1864):

> There are three words in the English language which derive the masculine form from the feminine. These are *widower*, *gander*, and *drake*. *Widow*, in Old English, is both masculine and feminine, as the word *spouse* still is ; but, as the word *widow* came to be used solely of women, the need of some distinction was felt, and *er* was added for the masculine. The old form for *goose* was *gans* or *gand*. Add the masculine ending *er*, and we have *gander*. The old word for *duck* was *and*; add the masculine suffix *rake*, and we have *andrake*, which is the old form of the word. It was then shortened into *drake*.

Comment: That's from the _easy_ grammar? I wonder what the hard one has.